# jQuery Tablesorter not sorting columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am parsing an XML file into a table and want to use the jquery tablesorter. Now that I've got the error to go away for tablesorter not existing, my data is populating in the table but the headers are not able to be sorted. Any ideas? Code is listed below for JS and HTML.

HTML:

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Read XML</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="custom.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <table id="table" border="1"> 
        <thead> 
            <tr> 
                <th>Item #</th> 
                <th>Shape</th> 
                <th>Weight</th> 
                <th>Color</th> 
                <th>Clarity</th> 
                <th>Price($)</th> 
           </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody> 
        </tbody> 
    </table> 
</body> 
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("#table").tablesorter(); 
$.ajax({ 
     type: "GET", 
     url: "tutorial.xml", 
     dataType: "xml", 
     success: parseXml 
}); 
$("#table").trigger("update"); 
}); 

function parseXml(xml) 
{ 
    $(xml).find("diamond").each(function() 
    { 
        $("#table tbody").after("<tr><td>" + $(this).find("id").text() +  
        "</td><td>" + $(this).find("shape").text() + "</td><td>" + $(this).find("weight").text() +  
        "</td><td>" + $(this).find("color").text() + "</td><td>" + $(this).find("clarity").text() +  
        "</td><td>" + $(this).find("price").text() + "</td></tr>"); 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Does the two typos fixed your code?

Comment: they fixed the problem from my last question of the tablesorter not being a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this line:

```
$("#table").trigger("update");
```

to the end of the parseXML method, and change `.after` to `.append`

```
function parseXml(xml) 
{ 
    $(xml).find("diamond").each(function() 
    { 
        $("#table tbody").append("<tr><td>" + $(this).find("id").text() +  
        "</td><td>" + $(this).find("shape").text() + "</td><td>" + $(this).find("weight").text() +  
        "</td><td>" + $(this).find("color").text() + "</td><td>" + $(this).find("clarity").text() +  
        "</td><td>" + $(this).find("price").text() + "</td></tr>"); 
    }); 
    $("#table").trigger("update");
}
```

Comment: Did you try the edit i added, changing `.after` to `.append`?

Comment: changing `.after` to `.append` did the trick...and so did moving the trigger statement to the end of parseXml.

Answer (score 2):

You need `$("#table").trigger("update");` at the end of `parseXml` to tell tablesorter that the table has been updated. It doesn't help if it is run before the ajaxRequest has returned.